# Check if path contains another in C++

Tags: c++, std

I'm looking to achieve something like

```cpp
if (basePath.contains(subPath)) {
    // subPath is a subPath of the basePath
}
```

I know I could achieve this by traversing the `subPath`'s parents, checking for `basePath` on the way.

Is there an `std` method for this?

---

`std::filesystem::path("/a/b/").contains("/a/b/c/d") == true`

Comment: Have you looked up https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem ?

Comment: @Jesper Yes, I have

Comment: Look for the example [recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: If you are looking for simple string comparisons, then something like `subPath.compare(0, basePath.size(), basePath) == 0` might do the trick.

Comment: What would be the expected result of "/b/c".contains("/a/b/c/d")? "/b/c" is a substring of "/a/b/c/d", but while checking directories, /a/b/c/d has nothing to do with /b/c. (So, in my opinion, `contains()` should be more like `startwith()`)

Comment: I've updated the question for more context. I'm working with paths, not strings. I don't want string operations.

Comment: How do you want to handle symlinks, `..`?

Comment: traverse them. Presumably, the OS would handle this - via the `path` API

Comment: Checking if `relative` path returns identity or not?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your requirements (i.e. what you consider to be a subpath), you could try analysing the result of [std::filesystem::relative()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative), for example:

```
bool is_subpath(const std::filesystem::path &path,
                const std::filesystem::path &base)
{
    auto rel = std::filesystem::relative(path, base);
    return !rel.empty() && rel.native()[0] != '.';
}
```

Note, this function returns `false` if the path relation cannot be determined, or if paths match.

Comment: Note: `std::filesystem::relative` resolves symbolic links while other solutions interpret the paths literally. (This was a plus for me, actually.)

Answer (score 2):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch can easily solve it in one line:

```
bool is_subpath(const fs::path& path, const fs::path& base) {
    const auto mismatch_pair = std::mismatch(path.begin(), path.end(), base.begin(), base.end());
    return mismatch_pair.second == base.end();
}
```

with the following tests (Catch2):

```
TEST_CASE("is_subpath", "[path]") {
    REQUIRE( is_subpath("a/b/c", "a/b") );
    REQUIRE_FALSE( is_subpath("a/b/c", "b") );
    REQUIRE_FALSE( is_subpath("a", "a/b/c") );
    REQUIRE_FALSE( is_subpath(test_root / "a", "a") );
    REQUIRE( is_subpath(test_root / "a", test_root / "a") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through items in both paths:

```
for (auto b = basePath.begin(), s = subPath.begin(); b != basePath.end(); ++b, ++s)
{
    if (s == subPath.end() || *s != *b)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```